# Postgresql function auto add 's' character to the end of string

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, function, postgresql-9.2

I have a function in PostgreSQL database. However, every time I run the function in PostgreSQL, it auto-adda the character **s** behind of the query, therefore, I receive an error when it executes.

An example query ends up looking like this:

```
WHAT IN HERE: query SELECT uom_id FROM ps_quantity where id = 11s
```

My version is PostgreSQL 9.2.13. How can I solve this? Thanks.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION select_field(
    selected_table text,
    selected_field text,
    field_type_sample anyelement,
    where_clause text DEFAULT ''::text)
  RETURNS anyelement AS
$BODY$ DECLARE
    -- Log
    ME  constant text := 'selected_field()';
    -- Local variables
        _qry          varchar := '';
        _result_value ALIAS FOR $0;
    where_clause1 varchar := 'asdasdsad';   
    BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'FUNCTION: SELECT_FIELD';
    -- BANGPH
    RAISE NOTICE 'BANGPH - CHANGE 11s to 11';

        _qry := 'SELECT uom_id FROM ps_quantity where id = 11';

    RAISE NOTICE 'WHERE = %s', where_clause1;                 

    RAISE NOTICE 'WHAT IN HERE: query %s', _qry;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[As the manual explains:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html)

instead of:

```
RAISE NOTICE 'WHAT IN HERE: query %s', _qry;
```

you need to use:

```
RAISE NOTICE 'WHAT IN HERE: query %', _qry;
```

Placeholders for the `RAISE` statement don't have a "type modifier", it's a plain `%`

Comment: well, you saved me from an error that I could not find out. Thanks.